# Samsung ML-2160 printer install

Tags: installation, drivers, printing

I need help a brand new Samsung ML-2160 printer installation on Ubuntu 12.04

The printer did not print all though it was recognized by my system and was labeled as "installed". Using different drivers (picked from list of drivers) didn't help.

I didn't know how to install the driver downloaded from Samsung but did it later very easily using sudo ./install.sh in download destination folder.

Comment: The ML1660 driver worked for me and seems the easiest path.

Answer (score 1):

- Download the unifiedLinuxDriver from this page: http://www.samsung.com/n_africa/support/model/ML-2160/SAU-downloads?downloadName=DR
- Extract the unified driver in home
- Open terminal and type the 3 comands
- `cd ~/cdroot`
- `ls`
- `sudo ./autorun`
- Application installation starts, just follow the steps.

finish

Answer (score 1):

Use ML-1660 driver from Ubuntu 12.04 instead of recommended ML2152 and printing will be OK!

Comment: This one which worked with me :).

Comment: The package name to install is printer-driver-splix

Comment: @jpa Thank you for your comment, installing this package helped me to set up ML-2160 on my RPI CUPS server. All I had to do was to find ppd file for the printer and this package!

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to use the slightly adjusted and packaged up version of the Samsung driver. It provides an easier way of installing it (just using packages) and some fixes for recent versions of Ubuntu like Apparmor with Cups, etc.

Available on [bchemnet.com](http://www.bchemnet.com/suldr/).

Answer (score 0):

On my system (32 bit) the install script continued to think that some component is missing, although I had installed sane, ghostscript and cusp. 
After some research I got it installed by replacing the following lines of the Linux/install.sh script...

```
# Set platform library directory suffix PLSFX
if [ "$HARDWARE_PLATFORM" = "x86_64" ]; then
    PLSFX=64
else
    PLSFX=
fi
```

... by ...

```
# Set platform library directory suffix PLSFX
if [ "$HARDWARE_PLATFORM" = "x86_64" ]; then
    PLSFX=64
else
    PLSFX=/i386-linux-gnu
fi
```

(IOW on my system the script didn't automatically detect the correct platform suffix.

Answer (score 0):

- Download the Unified Linux Driver from [this page](http://www.samsung.com/ru/support/model/ML-2160/XEV-downloads)
- its - [ Linux | V1.00.06 | Печать | 2013.08.06 | Многоязычное | 15.35 MB ]
- Extract the unified driver in `home`
- Open terminal and run: `sudo nautilus`
- move to Extracted folder (uld)
- Run in the terminal: `inistall.sh`
- In the terminal press `Enter` then read license press `Enter` (10 parts carefully)
- Press `y`
- Wait install
- Open System parameters -> Print -> Add a printer -> Select Samsung ml 2160 -> next -> ok, found draver -> check, print a test page -> happiness